# Trying to add a Node to the MySQL Innodb Cluster

Tags: mysql, azure, innodb

I have successfully created an Innodb cluster, I have 2 nodes which i wanted to join to the cluster but seems whenever I run the command to join the first node to the cluster it gives me below error:

```
Cluster.addInstance: WARNING: The given 'MySQL-Instance1:3306' and the peer 'MySQL-Cluster:3306' have duplicated server_id 1
ERROR: Error joining instance to cluster: 'MySQL-Instance1:3306' - Query failed. MySQL Error (3630): ClassicSession.query: Access denied; you need SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN and PERSIST_RO_VARIABLES_ADMIN privileges for this operation. Query: SET @@persist_only.server_id=/*(*/4097805574/*)*/: MySQL Error (3630): ClassicSession.query: Access denied; you need SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN and PERSIST_RO_VARIABLES_ADMIN privileges for this operation (RuntimeError)
```

It asks for somE sort of privialges that needED to be granted to my Cluster user i.e Cluster8171, also I had configured all the nodes with a user Cluster8171, I can access each one of the nodes using the user, but I cant add them, can anyone tell me whats being going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the same username and password is defined on both instances
2. If the mysql user includes a hostname or IP address, make sure *BOTH* usernames are defined.
3. ALSO:

> https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?177,665267,665310#msg-665310
>
> One more important point which I found was when adding an instance if
>   the ip whitelist has hostnames then the hostnames should match
>   hostname of the instance and should resolve to an IP address which can
>   be reached by other instances.

4. Finally, make sure `SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN` and `PERSIST_RO_VARIABLES_ADMIN` are included in the privileges granted to that user.

Comment: "Finally, make sure SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN and PERSIST_RO_VARIABLES_ADMIN are included in the privileges granted to that user." can you share the command for me? and where should I ran thE command on all the 3 instances?

Comment: `mysql > GRANT abc,..., xyz ON *.* TO 'username'@'host'....`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_system-variables-admin

Comment: Can you also tell me the best practices of creating a Innodb cluster in azure?

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON *.* TO 'Cluster8171'@'MySQL-Cluster'' at line 1 I got this error

Comment: I have granted access to the Cluster8171 user on all the 3 nodes, but when I tried to add the node to the cluster I am now getting the bElow error:c

ERROR: The account 'Cluster8171'@'%' is missing privileges required to manage an InnoDB cluster:
Missing global privileges: GRANT OPTION.
For more information, see the online documentation.
Cluster.addInstance: The account 'Cluster8171'@'%' is missing privileges required to manage an InnoDB cluster. (RuntimeError)

Comment: Now I get this error when I tried to join thE nodes after doing everythingc
It says server is not configured proprely to be addEd to the cLuster